# Как отключить автоформатирование в редакторе Atom?

Tags: atom

Не знаю как отключить автоформатирование в Atom. Пакет atom-beautify не установлен.

Comment: Возможно поможет отключение `whitespace`: [`Preferences → Packages → whitespace`](https://superuser.com/a/1044226/734823)

Comment: не помогает, увы

Comment: А что насчёт отключения `JSFormat`?

Comment: пробовал JSFormat, language-javascript, language-json - всё так же форматируется